# Plotting multiple states bokeh

Tags: bokeh, geo

I'm trying to plot two things:

1. Counties for MD, VA, and DC
2. Lats/Longs for housing listings in that area (most expensive in a certain color
   and least expensive in another color)

However, I'm having trouble with part 1, and cannot seem to plot the counties without getting the error message:

"Javascript error adding output!
Error: Error rendering Bokeh model: could not find tag with id: xxxxxxxxxxx
See your browser Javascript console for more details."

where xxxxx are numbers

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import (
ColumnDataSource,
HoverTool,
LogColorMapper)
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment import data as unemployment

palette.reverse()

va_counties = {
    code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == "va"
}
md_counties = {
    code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == "md"
}
dc_counties = {
    code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == "dc"
}

va_county_xs = [county["lons"] for county in va_counties.values()]
va_county_ys = [county["lats"] for county in va_counties.values()]

md_county_xs = [county["lons"] for county in md_counties.values()]
md_county_ys = [county["lats"] for county in md_counties.values()]

dc_county_xs = [county["lons"] for county in dc_counties.values()]
dc_county_ys = [county["lats"] for county in dc_counties.values()]

va_county_names = [county['name'] for county in va_counties.values()]
md_county_names = [county['name'] for county in md_counties.values()]
dc_county_names = [county['name'] for county in dc_counties.values()]


#county_rates = [unemployment[county_id] for county_id in counties]
color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=palette)

va_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=va_county_xs,
    y=va_county_ys,
    name=va_county_names,
))

md_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
     x=md_county_xs,
y=md_county_ys,
name=md_county_names,
))

dc_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=dc_county_xs,
    y=dc_county_ys,
    name=dc_county_names,
))

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,save"

va = figure(
    title="Texas Unemployment, 2009", tools=TOOLS,
    x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None
)
va.grid.grid_line_color = None

md = figure(
    title="Texas Unemployment, 2009", tools=TOOLS,
    x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None
)
md.grid.grid_line_color = None

dc = figure(
    title="Texas Unemployment, 2009", tools=TOOLS,
    x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None
)
dc.grid.grid_line_color = None

va.patches('x', 'y', source=va_source,
          fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=0.7, line_color="white", line_width=0.5)
md.patches('x', 'y', source=md_source,
          fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=0.7, line_color="white", line_width=0.5)
dc.patches('x', 'y', source=dc_source,
          fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=0.7, line_color="white", line_width=0.5)

hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Name", "@name"),
    ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)"),
]

show(va)
show(md)
show(dc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh maintains an implicit "current document" and by default everything you make gets added to that. This makes it very simple to have a script that generates one HTML file, and especially makes usage in the Jupyter notebook much more simple and transparent. In general this is a net positive, but it does make certain other usage patterns need to be slightly more verbose. In particular in your case with multiple `show` calls, each call to `show` gets the same document which is probably not what you intend. The solution is to create and show each plot in order, and call `reset_output` in between. Additionally, you would really need to specify unique filenames for each separate output, by using `output_file`. Here is a small complete example:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, reset_output, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# create and show one figure
p1 = figure(title="plot 1")
p1.circle([1,2,3], [4,6,5])

output_file("p1.html")
show(p1)

# clear out the "current document"
reset_output()

# create and show another figure
p2 = figure(title="plot 2")
p2.circle([1,2,3], [8,6,7])

output_file("p2.html")
show(p2)
```

There are other ways to do this by managing Bokeh `Document` objects explicitly yourself, but I would probably say this is the simplest to get started.

Comment: Doesn't this show two separate plots? I'm trying to "overlay" them (even though they don't intersect at all).

Comment: Yes it does, your intent was not clear from you post, so I made the best guess I could. If you just want to combine multiple glyphs on a plot, you are working too hard: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#combining-multiple-glyphs

Comment: Or perhaps worth explicitly stating: there is no way to overlay different *plots*. You can add multiple glyphs to a single plot, which is functionally the same thing. Alternatively, maybe you mean you want three plots, arranged in a column? In that case put them in a layout: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Bokeh has in its sample data, info on states and counties for each US state. I'm just trying to plot three (DC, VA, MD)  on the same plot